# Normalisation of random draws to $[0,1]^2$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, random

I have an $n\times 1$ vector $Y$ of numbers generated by drawing at random from the normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ [e.g. by using the function **normrnd** in Matlab].

In other words, for $n$ large, the histogram approximates well the density function of a random variable $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Is there a way to "rescale" each number contained in $Y$ to the interval $[0,1]$ in a way that "preserves" the original properties of $Y$?

For example, let $y_{max}$ and $y_{min}$ be respectively the maximum and minimum number contained in $Y$. Let $y_i$ be a number contained in $Y$. Do you think that $\frac{y_i-y_{min}}{y_{max}-y_{min}}$ could make the job?

---

***I am reformulating my question in a clearer and more general way thanks to the comments I received below:***

I have an $n\times 2$ matrix $Y$ of numbers generated by drawing at random from the bivariate normal distribution 
$$
N\Big(\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_1\\
\mu_2
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_1^2 & \rho \sigma_{1} \sigma_2\\
\rho \sigma_{1} \sigma_2 & \sigma^2_2\\
\end{pmatrix} \Big)
$$
 [e.g. by using the function **normrnd** in Matlab].

In other words, for $n$ large, the histogram approximates well the density function of a random vector $X\sim N\Big(\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_1\\
\mu_2
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_1^2 & \rho \sigma_{1} \sigma_2\\
\rho \sigma_{1} \sigma_2 & \sigma^2_2\\
\end{pmatrix} \Big)$.

Is there a way to "rescale" the numbers in $Y$ to the square $[0,1]^2$ in a way that "preserves" the original properties of $Y$? ***My ultimate objective is comparing the draws from the bivariate normal with the draws from a uniform distribution in $[0,1]^2$ via Kolmogorov-Smirnov.***

For example, let $Y_{j,max}$ and $Y_{j,min}$ be respectively the maximum and minimum numbers contained in the $j$th column of $Y$. Let $Y_{i,j}$ be the $ij$th element in $Y$. Do you think that $\frac{Y_{i,j}-Y_{j,min}}{Y_{j,max}-Y_{j,min}}$ could make the job for $j=1,2$?

From the comments below it seems that it doesn't due to variation in $Y_{j,max}$ and $Y_{j,min}$. Any other option suitable for a bivariate case would be extremely appreciated. One suggestion below was the application of a sort of 68–95–99.7 rule, but how can I generalise it to a bivariate normal with correlated random variables?

Comment: What kind of properties are you talking about?

Comment: For example the bell shape of the histogram

Comment: Well i think once you have a sample, normalising each sample will not change the counts. So the shape if the histogram will be preserved. But the normalized samples are not Gaussian anymore. Observe thaf $y_{min}$ and $y_{max} $ are random variables themselves. What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: You don't state your actual objective. For large $n$, max and min will be quite variable, so the histogram of the re-scaled 'data' may be centered far from $\mu.$ Is it feasible to transform $\mu \pm 4\sigma$ to $(0,1)$ and throw away any (very rare) value that is outside $\mu \pm 4\sigma$? Then each dataset will be treated the same, and still a sample from a (very slightly truncated) normal distribution.

Comment: Thanks. I need to compare the draws from a Normal with the draws from a Uniform in $[0,1]$. @BruceET I don't get your question about $\mu+4\sigma$

Comment: The normal distribution has an infinite support. You can sample from a truncated normal distribution instead  using rejection sampling. This way you only accept samples on the unit interval.

Comment: In your formula, just use $\mu-4\sigma$ instead of min and $\mu+4\sigma$ instead of max. $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu' = 1/2, \sigma'=1/8)$ goes outside $(0,1)$ with probability $6.3 \times 10^{-5}.$ Compare how? Kolmogorov-Smirnov test? Don't recommend trying acceptance sampling in Minitab.

Comment: @BruceET. Yes. Does the method you suggest work also with multivariate normals?

Comment: Something like it, yes. Depending on the goal, you might have to take any correlation into account. But that's way off-topic from your original question.

Comment: OK, let me reformulate my question. Thank you very much for your comments, they helped me a lot to better understand my problem.

Comment: This process is called "whitening" and described in innumerable books.

Comment: Thank you. So: doing "whitening" I transform $Y$ into $2$ new variables whose covariance is the identity matrix; then, I can apply separately to each variable the 68–95–99.7 rule to normalise it to the interval $[0,1]$?

Comment: If you're just interested in the Bell-shape, you can sample from a symmetric Dirichlet distribution. Using moment matching, you can get pretty similar behavior to the Bivariate normal.